# DataTable filtering issue in C sharp (Special characters used in the header)

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, google-sheets-api

I tried to filter my datagridview in C#, with  a code snippet I found, but I don't know what exactly should I write to the place of "Name".

It works if I filter columns which names are only one word, but in my case it can be sentences even. And if I use more than one word it throws a Syntax Error.

```
(dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name={0}",searchBox.Text);
```

Comment: see the RowFilter examples given [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Perfectly working in case of DataGridView's Column named as long sentences or consisting special characters. Use textbox with textChanged event in your winform:

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = PrintGrid17.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("[Customer Name] like '%{0}%' OR Phone like '%{0}%' OR [EMI 17 Collection Status and Month/Year] like '%{0}%'", txtSearchPrint17.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
        PrintGrid17.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: Did u find your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView
    .RowFilter = string.Format("Name='{0}'", searchBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
```

It surrounds your search string with single quotes, which is the required syntax, and escapes any single quotes in your search string by doubling them.